# When can $\mathbb{N}$ (or any other set) be used as an exponent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intuitively, you would say that if $\mathbb{N}²$ is the set of all vectors of two natural numbers, and correspondingly for $\mathbb{N}³$, then $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ stands for the set of all vectors of any natural length (what is sometimes called $\mathbb{N}^*$). I've seen cases where this expression is used in a very different manner, like $2^\mathbb{N}$ for the power set, or $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ for the functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.
Is there a general way of using sets as exponents?

Comment: Using $\Bbb{N^N}$ for the finite sequences of natural numbers is just terrible, and doing so should be punished swiftly and severely.

Comment: I know, but I'm confident that many "illiterate" will follow that intuition... It's shorter, for example, than $\mathbb{N}^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Use $\Bbb{N^{<N}}$.

Comment: Good. I'm not familiar with that "minor" sign, what's its precise meaning here?

Comment: All it means that you take all the proper initial segments of $\Bbb N$, which correspond to the finite sequences.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, there's no need to try punishing anyone - furthermore, I tend to work under the assumption that people are pretty strong, and that attempts to punish them will backfire severely. A much, *much* better comment would have simply explained that using $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ in this way causes a conflict with certain existing conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have explained, $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^*$ are different. Nonetheless, they can be viewed as special cases of the same underlying idea as follows:

> **Definition 0.** By a *slate*, lets mean a set $X$ equipped with a collection of subsets deemed *supportive*; so kind of like a topological space, but with the phrase "open subset" replaced by "supportive subset", and with no conditions imposed on the collection of supportive subsets.
>
> **Definition 1.** Given a set $Y$ and a slate $X$, write $Y^X$ for the set of all functions $f$ such that there exists a supportive subset $S$ of $X$ satisfying $f : Y \leftarrow S$.

Then:

- Each set $X$ can be made into a slate by regarding $X$ as the only supportive subset. Under this identification, $Y^X$ just means the set of all functions $Y \leftarrow X$.
- Letting $*$ denote the slate whose underlying set is $\mathbb{N}$, and whose supportive subsets are precisely the lowersets that are bounded above, we see that $Y^*$ can indeed be identified with the set of words in $Y$.
- More generally, each ordinal $\alpha$ can be made into a slate $<\alpha$ by taking supportive subsets to be precisely the lowersets that are bounded above. This allows us to write $Y^{<\omega}$ for the set of words in $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Asaf that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is terrible notation for the space of finite sequences of natural numbers. If you have sets, say $X$ and $Y$, and you see $Y^{\!X}$, it almost always denotes the set$^{\ast}\!$ of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Even when you see the notation $2^{X}$ used for the power set of $X$, this is really just a clever way of expressing the power set using the other meaning for the notation. Think of $2$ as a set that contains two elements which we'll (cleverly) name $\mathrm{true}$ and $\mathrm{false}$. So if we have a function $f$ from a set $X$ to the set $\{\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{false}\}$, we can think of $f$ as representing a subset of $X$: every element sent to $\mathrm{true}$ is in the subset and every element sent to $\mathrm{false}$ is not in the subset. In this way there is a one-to-one correspondence between the functions of $2^X$ and all the subsets of $X$, so $2^X$ can be thought of as the power set of $X$.

---

$(\ast)$ There is a nit-picky subtlety here. When one writes $Y^{\!X}$, this is usually considered to be a *set* of functions. Sometimes though, like in category theory, if $X$ and $Y$ are objects in some category, the *set* of morphisms (which are like functions only cooler) from $X$ to $Y$ is instead denoted $\hom(X,Y)$, and the notation $Y^{\!X}$ is reserved to denote something a little more sophisticated called an [exponential object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object) in that category.

Answer (score 2):

$Y^X$ generally indicates the space of all maps from $X$ to $Y$.

The $2^X$ notation is simply a shorthand for the powerset $\mathcal{P} (X)$. It came from the fact that $|2^X| = 2^{|X|}$ for any finite $X$.

Comment: And from the def'n of the ordinals$ 0=\phi, 1=\{0\}, 2=\{0,1\}.$ So we can identify $\{0,1\}^X$ with $P(X)$ by identifying each member of $P(X)$ with its characteristic function.